# Getting pandas.read_csv to handle whitespace in first column of .txt

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having difficulties getting pandas to read a .txt-file whose first column contains sections of data, leaving some of its rows blank. The raw data is separated by multiple whitespaces of different lengths, and has format:

```
Sensor  Value  Name  Case 
sec01   379    S01   H4   
sec02   1183   S02   A1   
        948    S03   A1   
        6948   S04   A1   
        2      S05   C1   
sec03   -722   S06   E1   
        -466   S07   B1   
        -289   S08   F1   
        -105   S09   F1
```

Where the sensor column is filled with whitespace for indentation where there is no "sensor" cell.
Passing:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename,
                 sep = '\s+',
                 header = None,
                 skipinitialspace = False,
                 encoding = 'unicode_escape',
                 engine = 'python'
                 )
```

, results in output of the form:

```
Sensor  Value  Name  Case 
sec01     379   S01    H4   
sec02    1183   S02    A1   
948       S03    A1  None
6948      S04    A1  None
2         S05    C1  None
sec03    -722   S06    E1   
-466      S07    B1  None
-289      S08    F1  None
-105      S09    F1  None
```

Where columns get mixed up. The desired output is to have `None` or `NaN` for missing "sensor" cells.
What would be the correct separator/delimiter input in this case? Or does .txt-file need to be rearranged beforehand?

Comment: `read_csv` is for (comma) **separated values** files. This is a Fixed Width Fields files, hence read_csv cannot process it correctly. Better to use `read_fwf`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pandas [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) to read the data as fixed-width formatted lines and then forward-fill the null values in `Sensor`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """Sensor  Value  Name  Case 
sec01   379    S01   H4   
sec02   1183   S02   A1   
        948    S03   A1   
        6948   S04   A1   
        2      S05   C1   
sec03   -722   S06   E1   
        -466   S07   B1   
        -289   S08   F1   
        -105   S09   F1   """

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(data))
df["Sensor"] = df.Sensor.fillna(method="ffill")
df
```

Result:

```
  Sensor  Value Name Case
0  sec01    379  S01   H4
1  sec02   1183  S02   A1
2  sec02    948  S03   A1
3  sec02   6948  S04   A1
4  sec02      2  S05   C1
5  sec03   -722  S06   E1
6  sec03   -466  S07   B1
7  sec03   -289  S08   F1
8  sec03   -105  S09   F1
```

Comment: Yep! One answer that does not try to use `read_csv` for a file which is not a CSV! Definitely deserves a +1 :-)

Comment: You don't need to use the StringIO to feed in the file to the fwf

Comment: @AlexAMP, yes, of course. My intent was to have a fully reproducible answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is fixed-width so you can use the `pd.read_fwf` function to read in the data.

```py
df = pd.read_fwf(filename)
```

Pretty useful read in method if you find yourself with well-structured data- [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html)